# Iterating metacharacters for regex in Stata

Tags: regex, string, stata

I'm currently using regular expressions to manipulate street names in Stata. I'm faced with a problem that requires me to select observations based on how long a certain word is in the string. I know that you can specify the iteration of expressions using curved brackets in other engines, but this doesn't seem to be working in Stata. Specifically, I want to select observations that have three or more alpha numeric characters in a certain point in the string, which should be coded by

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}
```

However, this doesn't work when I try it in Stata, nor do any other uses of {} work, even though online debuggers say it should be correct. Is this a deficiency in the Stata implementation of regex? I'm working on a solution that doesn't need that iteration, but I'd like to hear from the community on what is lacking in regex in Stata, and if there's a different way to iterate expressions in the program.

Comment: `curved brackets`, `in a certain point in the string`.. what do you mean by this ? Can you provide a quote from _stata_ docs on just what kind of regex engine they use ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the new Unicode regexp parser in Stata 14 (based on the ICU standard) can use this notation to find patterns that repeat at least k times:

```
clear

input str50 address
"221B Baker Street"
"56B, Whitehaven Mansions"
"Danemead, High street, St. Mary Mead"
end

compress

list address if ustrregexm(address,"([0-9]){3,}")
```

This will only give you Sherlock's address since it has 3 or more numbers. It also looks like you can use character classes:

```
list address if ustrregexm(address,"([:digit:]){3,}")
```

The *regular* regexp parser has [never supported](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2005-09/msg00364.html) this shortcut capacity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limiting quantifier in Stata according to the [documentation](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/).

> **Other popular regular-expression syntaxes include** the POSIX standard and Perl’s standard. Both expand on these basic operators by including **counting operators (use of curly braces)**, metacharacters (usually of the form :alpha:, etc.), and other syntax-specific additions.
>
> When presented with the choice of which regular-expression syntax to adopt, Stata has several options. Different operating systems offer their own regular-expression parsers for applications to use, but there is no guarantee that these parsers are consistent. **Stata avoids this ambiguity by using its own parser.**

You just need to repeat the subpattern "manually" (as in some examples on the documentation Web page):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Comment: @sln: I guess the author just meant to say that Stata does not need all the features other regex flavors have, especially those listed above.